# Response from Cloudfront from S3 Origin keeps changing CORS Headers

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cors

here is my problem :
CORS are set as supposed to be on the S3 :

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

when I try to fetch a file (using jQuery with option CrossDomain = true)

from **A.example.com** -> **B.example.com/file.js**  (works with correct Headers)
When I try the same request from another domain : 
**C.dev.example.com** -> **B.example.com/file.js** // (it fails)

However for the second example when I look at the network logs in chrome 
my first request  OPTIONS:

it has the correct CORS response headers :

```
access-control-allow-headers: access-control-allow-headers
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 3000
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:38:36 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
via: 1.1 f19281f08e79aa6c6634266c50732dd5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: S2aMKSsJspB9p2RVxLMNh49iQ3Rc0Uims-EEIcjbxC42_OpqJpoUXQ==
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

However the GET Request (right after the OPTIONS) :

```
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 817
content-type: application/javascript
date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:19:46 GMT
etag: "5b85d498318db8095a776fdcae57c624"
last-modified: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:19:20 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
via: 1.1 f19281f08e79aa6c6634266c50732dd5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: C0xswS08mXDHkagm3phQT59wjclwEX9ZZHXr57OpZVMHzkf432H7dg==
x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
```

My TTL on the Cloudfront is 5 seconds (It has to be aggressive for my use case)
I'm using the **h2** protocol instead of the **http/1.1**

Answer (score 0):

This is related to : [Chrome S3 Cloudfront: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on initial XHR request](https://serverfault.com/questions/856904/chrome-s3-cloudfront-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-on-initial-xhr-req/856948#856948)

More info in here :  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=796312